# Insert a Date parameter in the constructor of a class object

Tags: java, class, date, constructor

I have to create a Cinema project in Java using BlueJ.
I have a Class named Movie and a Class named Show.
In the Show constructor I want to insert some parameters and I want one to be the date and time of the show using "Date".
It should be something like this:

```
public Show(int ID, Movie movie, Date date, int seats)
```

But I am not able to insert the date. Is there a way to enter it or is it impossible to do it this way?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Why are you not able to insert the date?  How are you trying to do it, and what errors or unexpected behavior are you seeing?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: I mean that when I click in BlueJ in new show, I don´t know which is the format in which the date is inserted. The error I get is Error: <identifier> expected, or Error: incompatible types. int cannot be converted to java.util.Date.

Answer (score 3):

That should be possible if you structure your class like this:

```
public class Show {
    private int id;
    private Movie movie;
    private Date date;
    private int seats;

    public Show(int ID, Movie movie, Date date, int seats) {
        this.id = ID;
        this.movie = movie;
        this.date = date;
        this.seats = seats;
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to call this constructor:

```
Show show = new Show(5, new Movie(), new java.util.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()), 24);
```

If you want to specify a specific date, you should use the `SimpleDateFormat` class.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
java.util.Date yourDate = sdf.parse("1992-07-26");
```

Answer (score 1):

The main issue that you need to use `java.util.Date` as your object.
There is another Date object which is used for SQL.

- [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)
- [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html)

So just add `import java.util.Date;` in each file you want to use this certain object.

Comment: In Eclipse,  you can autoimport using ctrl+shift+O. /protip